# A fair six sided dice is rolled 4 times

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, solution-verification

I have this problem I am working on about permutations. I just want to know if what I am doing is correct.

> A fair six-sided die is tossed four times and the numbers shown are recorded in a sequence. How many different sequences are there?

So by the rules of permutations, I used the formula:

$$P(n,r) = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$$
$$P(6,4) = \frac{6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}{2 \cdot 1}$$

which gave me the answer $360$. Is this correct? Another thought is saying since a dice has six sides, it only has six permutations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not correct.

You are assuming that the digits cannot repeat, when in fact they can. There are $6$ possibilities for the first digit of the sequence, $6$ possibilities for the second, and $6$ possibilities for the third and fourth. The order of the digits matters.

Hence there are $6^4 = 1296$ different sequences.

Comment: The numbers shown? Are they not refering to the number that comes at the top? Like how many different possible outcomes to expect?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. There's nothing stopping you from getting something like $4444$ or $5555$ as a sequence.

Comment: But I don't understand why they would bring such a question on a topic about permutations. I don't see how it applies to permutations, judging by your answer.

Comment: This still uses permutations, just that they are permutations with repetition. I'm assuming you're used to seeing permutations *without* repetition, which are given by $P(n, r)$. When you have permutations with repetition, there are the same number of choices for each number, and so you just have $6 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 \cdot 6$.

Comment: Ok I get it now since it's a dice, the numbers can repeat. I am starting to get the sense of this.

Comment: @chaulap No problem! Thanks for the accept.